# Replace portions of a url path and query string using .htaccess and Regex?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I replace :

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=7377
```

By:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/artigos/7377
```

I tried this :

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=(.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=\/([0-9]{4}-.*)$ /artigos/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: To which results did your attempts lead to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot capture query string in `RewriteRule`. Use a `RewriteCond` instead. Use this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?option=com_k2&view=item&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.portal-gestao.com/artigos/%1? [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with RewriteCond Query String matching code:

```
# Individual explicit redirect rules based on exact matching URI|Query String parameters
# $1? Strip the option=com_k2&view=item&id=7377 Query String from the destination URI
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_k2&view=item&id=7377$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /artigos/7377/$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_k2&view=item&id=7378$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /artigos/7378/$1? [R=301,L]

# Dynamically redirect all matching Query Strings to equivalent URI
# %2 match and redirect to equivalent 4 digit number URI
# $1? Strip the option=com_k2&view=item&id= portion of the Query String from the destination URI
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=com_k2&view=item&id+)=([0-9]{4}+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /artigos/%2/$1? [R=301,L]
```