# URL Redirect like WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to have the links easier to read. So I read a lot and found the system of WordPress.
They take the normal URL like abc.com/page.php?p=2 and substitute to abc.com/aboutus/.

But how can I do this?

I think it have to deal with .htaccess but only the Redirect isn't helpfull.
I've tried already

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?section=([a-z0-  9]+)&title=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&title=$2   [L,NC]
```

in the .htaccess

But the result is not really good.

I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Kind Regards

Ascawath :)

Comment: WordPress does internal rewriting (Database) as well as htaccess rewriting. The WordPress internal rewriting rewrites pages and posts p=xxxx to custom permalink structures that you choose in WordPress settings. If you want to do rewriting based on Query Strings then see this StackOverflow topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353625/replace-index-phpoption-com-k2view-itemid-using-htaccess-and-regex/36360949#36360949

Comment: Tahnks.
But in this case there has to be the file named artigos/7737, aren't there?
If i wanted to do it like Wordpress with internal rewriting. How can I do this?

Kind Regards

Comment: Yes, you would actually have to have a destination URI|URL that really exists or else you would then get a 404 error because the rewrite/redirect would go to a URI|URL that does not really exist. So based on the information you posted you would have this destination URL|URL: /aboutus/.

Comment: But WordPress doesn't make for each Article a new Folder, does it?
So how does WordPress redirect to these articles?

Comment: Correct. A folder is not the same thing as a URI|URL. A URI can point to a physical folder or can be dynamically generated, but in both cases the URI must exist.  When you create a Post or Page in WordPress you give the Post or Page a Title and that Title is the URI|URL. The Title URI|URL is saved to the WordPress database. Each/every WordPress Post/Page has a Post/Page ID. ?p=N where N is the Post ID number. WordPress rewrites the ?p=N Query String using both internal rewriting and htaccess code rewriting.

Comment: Thanks. So can you give me an example, please? I'm not sure how to do this myself. What is in the htaccess and what is the code for php?

Comment: I posted in example of htaccess code in an earlier comment. Trying to explain how to do what WordPress is already doing would be foolish since it is very advanced and very complex. If you are not an experienced coder then even looking at the WordPress code would probably not get you anywhere. What I recommend is you forget about trying to do what WordPress is doing and instead just simply redirect by Query Strings using htaccess code.