# Using .htacces to rewrite Dynamic URLs to Static URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

Using .htaccess I would like to rewrite Dynamic URLs to Static URLs as follows:

/proddetail.php?prod=xyz123

to become just

/xyz123

I have tried many suggested solutions, way to many to list here, but to no avail. I just can't find the solution and I'm completely at a loss. Any assistance gratefully received.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: I think I may have tried maybe 100 - and I'm still trying. Its impossible to list them.

Comment: Start with 5 and we can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?prod=$1 [L]
```

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: Nice interesting tool ! Good pick and quick answer guarantied :)

Comment: No. That didn't do it.

Comment: Have you tried the tool I mentioned above? Play with it, give it a shot. Also, do you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: Oh yes. Tried that tool and every other tool I could find, When I said 24 hours I wasn't joking.

Comment: Rewrite/Redirect Query Strings to URI's:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353625/replace-index-phpoption-com-k2view-itemid-using-htaccess-and-regex/36360949#36360949

Comment: Interesting. Based on that link I tries this RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /proddetail\.php\?prod=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com/%1? [L,R=302] and it did rewrite to the correct url but it gave a 404