# mod_rewrite - insert param to path - why are there 3 headers?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After all these years in web developing and all those tutorials, I am still not sure how mod_rewrite exactly works and need your help!

I have URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?search_expression=foo&otherInstance=bar
```

More or or less or different parameters apart from other Instance are possible. I want it to redirect to

```
http://example.com/bar/index.php?search_expression=foo&test=val
```

(&test=val is for testing only.)

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      GET\s\/?(.*)\?(.*)otherInstance=([^\&]*)(&?\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /%3/?%2%4&test=val                  [L]
```

But get an server Error. It says:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

When I add [R] it redirects to the correct path, but the rest of the parameters are lost. Seeing the network protocol show that there are three headers then, one with the old parameters (otherInstance, search_expression), one with the new one (search_expression, test) and one empty. So there must be something fundamental wrong, but how many examples i study, I cannot figure out what it is. So please enlighten me!

~ Edit ~

Maybe I have to explain what is meant by the last part a bit more: When type the URL above into the browser, I get redirected to

```
http://example.com/bar/index.php
```

Without a visible querystring. A look into the network protocol shows, that the GET part of the query is being send three times, as said above. The PHP script naturally takes the last one for $_GET which is empty. The first contains the origin GET parameters (search_expression=foo&otherInstance=bar) and the second the desired one (search_expression=foo&test=val) and the third one is empty. So what I do can't be that wrong? My question why they is a third and empty $_GET part in the query.

~ Edit 2 ~

Thanks to Panama Jack i tried to add a second question mark in the replacement string and no it acts like it should. But I have not the sligtiest clue why, if anyone could explain that I would me more than happy! The rule no is

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      GET\s\/?(.*)\?(.*)otherInstance=([^\&]*)(&?\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /%3/?%2%4?                  [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by

> When I add [R] it redirects to the correct path, but the rest of the
>   parameters are lost.

If you are just trying to change the URL to remove a parameter, you should be able to just do a redirect like this.

This should match no matter where in the URL search_expression&otherInstance is found together.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)search_expression=([^&]+)&otherInstance=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php?search_expression=%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: The `?` in the replacement string means to discard any query string parameters from the original request. So that just leaves the one in the replacement string you specified.

Answer (score 0):

The mod_rewrite RewriteRule directive without the R flag allows you to rewrite pages in the background/silently (layman's terms).
Example:  `RewriteRule ^example-uri/(.*)$ /path-to-file/example.php [L]`
So what a visitor to the example-uri page will see is the URI|URL to the example-uri page, but the actual content of the page will be the contents of the /path-to-file/example.php file.

When you use the R flag you would be redirecting to another URI|URL instead of rewriting content silently in the background.
Example:  `RewriteRule ^example-uri/(.*)$ /path-to-file/example.php [R]`
A visitor to the example-uri page will be redirected to /path-to-file/example.php and will see the URI|URL for the example.php page.

Query Strings are a different kind of animal that are handled/processed differently by Browsers than typical/standard "static" URI's|URL's.
A question mark signifies the start of a Query string and a Browser starts processing the Query String parameters at the question mark.
Query Strings are cached by Browsers so if you are changing things with your Query String htaccess code then you should clear your browser cache in-between each change you make to your htaccess code.

Ok so it looks like what you want is a Redirect and Query String replacement using this htaccess code:

```
# Match, Redirect & replace the search_expression=foo&otherInstance=bar Query String 
# Destination URI with Query String replacement: http://example.com/bar/index.php?search_expression=foo
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_expression=foo&otherInstance=bar$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/$1?search_expression=foo [R=301,L]
```

More Info & Examples about Query Strings: Stripping, adding or replacing Query Strings & redirects
http://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/htaccess-redirect-code-where-do-i-add-redirect-htaccess-code/

Comment: That would be the solution, if the things where that static. But searchExpression can be something else (that's trivial), it's also optional at all. Finally the order of the parameters are not fixed. To make it compatible with future changes, it should work also with more parameters at the beginning or the end of the query string. That's why I use this complicated RegEx above. It breaks the Query String correctly into parts, but when I want to rebuild everything I get the correct header with the replaced querystring AND - and that's my  problem - a  third and empty one.

Comment: I don't know why I use THE_REQUEST instead of QUERY_STRING like you btw but I doubt this is a point here.

Comment: Yep, I thought about adding all the possible dynamic Query String Regex possibilities in my example code above, but just decided to get you started with some general/basic code. I think the best route to take is doing RewriteCond QUERY_STRING matches instead of using THE_REQUEST. You have to have something "constant" that you can match with/from using Regex or you will just end up going around in circles. So you would just need to include all/every possible matching Regex conditions by adding additional RewriteCond QUERY_STRING matching conditions.

Comment: This is just a general example of adding additional RewriteCond QUERY_STRING matching conditions and is not specific to the exact code you are looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353625/replace-index-phpoption-com-k2view-itemid-using-htaccess-and-regex/36360949#36360949